Partial derivatives proof
I am working through a mechanics proof, and have reduced the problem to a point where it is sufficient to show that
$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\dot{q}}}\frac{d}{dt}f=\frac{\partial}{\partial{q}}\frac{d}{{dt}}f$. Where $f=f(q(t),t)$ and $\dot{q}=\frac{d}{dt}q$.
This seems intuitivly clear to me. In that in some way taking the derivative w.r.t changes the velocity differential on the denominator to a position differential. However I am not sure how to express this formally. All help and hints are appreciated.

This is the chain rule

Apply chain rule to $\dot f$
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\sum_{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_i}\dot q_i$$
Now partially derive wrt $\dot q_i$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot q_i}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_i}$$
If you now differentiate wrt $t$ we get
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot q_i}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}f=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}f$$
where in the last step we interchanged both differential operators.

Could you possibly expand on the second equation. I don't really see this result.

Could you specify what's giving you trouble?

@Cow $\tfrac{\partial f(q,t)}{\partial t}$ and $\tfrac{\partial f(q,t)}{\partial q}$ are not functions of $\dot q$, so....$$\small\begin{align}\def\d{\mathrm d}\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial{\dot q}}\dfrac{\d~~}{\d t}f(q,t)&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{\dot q}}\left(\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial t}f(q,t)+\dot q\cdot\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial q}f(q,t)\right)\&=\left(0+1\cdot\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial q}f(q,t)+\dot q\cdot 0\right)\&=\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial q}f(q,t)\end{align}$$

${\text{Also:}\\def\d{\mathrm d}\def\p{\partial}\def\f#1#2{\dfrac{#1}{#2}}\small\quad\begin{align}\f{\d~~}{\d t}\f{\p f}{\p q}&=\f{\d q}{\d t}~\f{\p^2 f}{\p q~^2}+\f{\p^2 f}{\p t~\p q}\&=\left(\f{\p~~}{\p q}\f{\d q}{\d t}~\f{\p f}{\p q}+\f{\d q}{\d t}~\f{\p^2 f}{\p q~^2}\right)+\f{\p^2 f}{\p q~\p t}\&=\f{\p~~}{\p q}\left(\f{\d q}{\d t}\f{\p f}{\p q}+\f{\p f}{\p t}\right)\&=\f{\p ~~}{\p q}\f{\d f}{\d t}\end{align}}$
